# Magento 1.9 Change Product Status Programmatically

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I'm currently looking for a method to programmatically change the product status of all my products if a certain amount of stock is reached.

Ideally I would like to set all products to status Disabled if the Stock level is under 10. All others that are 10 and more , the product status should become Enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with this code by creating one php file to the root directory or you can create cron scheduler if you want to do this process for some time period.

```
        error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
        $mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
        require_once $mageFilename;
        Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
        ini_set('memory_limit', '600M');
        ini_set('max_execution_time', 1800);
        umask(0);
        Mage::app('admin');
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        foreach ($collection as $_data) {
            $productCat = $_data->getCategoryIds();
            $stock      = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_data);
            $productqty = $stock->getQty();
            if (intval($productqty) < 10) {
                $productModel  = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
                $productUpdate = $productModel->load($_data->getId());
                $productUpdate->setStatus(2);
                $productUpdate->save();
            }
            else
            {
                $productModel  = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
                $productUpdate = $productModel->load($_data->getId());
                $productUpdate->setStatus(1);
                $productUpdate->save();
            }
        }
```